# Fetch test detail from a file with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have following test detail in my `py` file, which I am trying to get with regular expression.

```
>>> a = '''
... def test_1(self, a, b):
...     """
...     @desc description
...     @para parameter
...     """
... '''
```

Here is what I tried:

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*(def\s+test_.*\"\"\".*\"\"\").*', a)
[]
```

Can someone please help me in figuring out if I am missing anything?

Comment: isn't problem that you need multiline regexp ? 
`re.compile(r"<your regexp>", re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the re.DOTALL flag to match the newlines in your test detail, but be careful with combining greedy .* matches with re.DOTALL

The following will work with multiple tests in the same file, using non-greedy (.*?) matches:

```
import re

a = '''
    def test_1(self, a, b):
    """
    @desc description
    @para parameter
    """
    def test_2(self, a, b):
    """
    @desc description
    @para parameter
    """
    '''

pattern = re.compile('\s*def\s+test_.*?""".*?"""', re.DOTALL) 
set = pattern.findall(a)
for item in set:
    print "MATCH:"
    print item
```

This produces the following output:

```
MATCH:
        def test_1(self, a, b):
        """
        @desc description
        @para parameter
        """
MATCH:
        def test_2(self, a, b):
        """
        @desc description
        @para parameter
        """
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern is correct but you have to use re.DOTALL flag as .* will not match new line character.

```
>>> re.findall(r'.*(def\s+test_.*\"\"\".*\"\"\").*',a,re.DOTALL)
['def test_1(self, a, b):\n\t"""\n\t@desc description\n\t@para parameter\n\t"""']
```